# Python. Trying to make 3 lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've asked this question here before, and i've fixed up my code a bit, but im still having problems with the output. This is for a project for school, so im not after answers, but I do need some help.

This is my desiered output

```
{'Name': 'Humboldt', 'Candidates': {'LIB': 'Elliott', 'NDP': 'Angela', 'SK': 'Mr. Robot'}, 'Votes': {'LIB': 2732, 'NDP': 101, 'SK': 370}}
```

My current output is this:

```
{'Name': 'Humboldt'}
{'LIB': 'Elliott', 'NDP': 'Angela', 'SK': 'Mr. Robot'}
{'LIB': 2732, 'NDP': 101, 'SK': 370}
```

My code looks like this:

```
def index_district(list1, list2, list3):
 import numpy

 name = ["Name"]

 district = [list2[0]]

 dis = dict(zip(name, district))

 list1.pop(0)

 list2.pop(0)

 canidate_parties = dict(zip(list3 , list2))

 party_votes = dict(zip(list3, list1))

 zipped_dic = dict(zip( canidate_parties,party_votes))

 dic = dict(zip(dis, zipped_dic))

 print (dis)

 print (canidate_parties)

 print (party_votes)


 A = numpy.array((dis, canidate_parties, party_votes))

index_district(['Humboldt',2732,101,370],['Humboldt','Elliott','Angela','Mr. Robot'],['LIB','NDP','SK'])
```

I've looked online but i cant seem to figure out how to do this.  I'm not looking for answers, but if anyone could offer some help that would be appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For one thing, you're never assigning a key of `'Candidates'` or `'Votes'`.

Comment: So i want to just get a dictionary of candidates and a dictionary of votes?  or are you telling me to add the candidates and votes in of my output?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it looks like you want `dis['Candidates'] = candidate_parties` and `dis['Votes'] = party_votes`.

Comment: Also, the line `dic = dict(zip(dis, zipped_dic))` creates a variable `dic` but you never use it anywhere.  Did you mean to assign it to `dis` instead of `dic`?

Comment: @JohnGordon  You're right about the dic never being used.  I must have left it from when i was fixing my code.

Comment: Oh my god that fixed it.  You are a god.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
def index_district(list1, list2, list3):
    dictionary = {}
    name = dictionary['Name'] = list1.pop(0)
    list2.pop(0)
    zip1 = dictionary['Candidates'] = dict(zip(list3, list2))
    zip2 = dictionary['Votes'] = dict(zip(list3, list1))
    print(dictionary)
```

You never assigned the key of 'Candidates' and 'Votes' to their respective values.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it very much, however I wouldn't feel right using code someone else made for me.  But i will study what you did.  Thank you.